# badge statistic broken on SE Moderator Candidate Statistic page for RU.SO

Tags: bug, localization, election-page, russian-stackoverflow

Look at the [SE Moderator Candidate Statistic page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#ru.stackoverflow) for StackOverflow in Russian.

Badge statistic is broken and shows all badges as absent for each candidate:

[image]

The possible reason is that badges' names are localized.

It would be great if the page used localized names, but at least it should show received badges.

Comment: Tim Stone's looking into a way to fix that one up.